# remove characters and blank space from string

Tags: c#, listbox

I have a listbox with for example this values:

> 1 - Value
>   55 - Value

What can I do to convert my string and select only `Value` deleting `55 - "blank space"` I think that maybe I could do 2 splits, one to delete the `-` and the other to delete the number, but I want to know a simple way to do this.

Comment: is that a CRLF single string or an array of strings?

Comment: Good point, it's just a simple string, `string value1 = "1 - value"`

Comment: `myListbox.SelectedItem.ToString().Split()[0]` give you the number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use substring:

```
var idx = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString().IndexOf('-');
string val = listBox.SelectedItem.ToString().SubString(idx+1).Trim();
```

or more defensive:

```
var idx = value1.IndexOf('-');
if( idx != -1 ){
   string val = value1.SubString(idx+1).Trim();
}
```

Comment: Yes this could be a solution, but I don't explain my problem very well, I need to do this but with an element off a listbox, maybe I should change `value1` to `myListbox.selecteditem`?

Comment: what is that type (I don't remember)?  Are you using WPF or winforms?

Comment: Is a Windows Form application

Comment: ok, so you need to know the data type of SelectedItem, what is it?

Comment: I don't want to know the data type, I want to get that value, if I do `myListbox.SelectedItem` I will get `1 - Value or 55 - Value` that's ok, now what I want is to make an split or something just to get `Value` deleting the rest of the item `1 - or 55 -` etc.

Comment: That's why I ask if I need to change `value1.IndexOf('-')` to my `listbox.SelectedItem.IndexOf` or what?

Comment: if SelectedItem is a string, ugh.  why don't you try it? =)